# Introducton books for ‎$\frak{E}_p(I)$

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, linear-programming

Are there any good books different from abstract harmonic analysis by hewitt to study  ‎$\frak{E}_p(I)$. where  ‎$\frak{E}_p(I)$ is: ‎Let $I$ be an arbitrary index set‎. ‎For each $i\in I$ let $H_i$ be a finite dimensional Hilbert space of dimension $d_i$‎, ‎and let $a_i$ be a real number $\geq{1}$‎. ‎The $\ast-algebra$ $\prod_{i\in{I}}\mathcal{B}(H_i)$‎, ‎will denoted by $\frak{E}{(I)}$; scaler multiplication‎, ‎addition‎, ‎multiplication‎, ‎and the adjoint of an element are defined coordinatewise‎.

Is there any good book different from abstract harmonic analysis by hewitt for studying  ‎$\frak{E}_p(I)$? Where  ‎$\frak{E}_p(I)$ is: ‎Let $E=(E_i)_{i}$ be an element of $\frak{E}{(I)}.$ For $p\geq0$‎, ‎we define‎
‎$$\|E\|_{p}=\Big( \sum_{i=1}{a_i\|E_i\|}^{p}_{\varphi_p}\Big)^{1/p}$$‎
‎and‎
‎$$\|E\|_{\infty}=\sup\{\|E_i\|_{\varphi_{\infty}},~i\in I\}.$$‎
‎Note that for $o\leq p<\infty$‎, 
‎$$\|E_i\|_{\varphi_p}=\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{n}{|s_{j}^{i}|}^p\Big)^{1/p}$$ and‎
‎$$\|E_i\|_{\varphi_{\infty}}=sup\lbrace{s_{1}^{i},s_{2}^{i},...,s_{d_{i}}^{i}}\rbrace,$$‎
‎where $(s_{1}^{i},s_{2}^{i},...,s_{d_{i}}^{i})$ is the sequence of eigenvalues of operator $|E_{i}|$‎, ‎written in any order‎. ‎For $p\geq0$‎, ‎$\frak{E}_p(I)$ is defined as the set of all $E\in\frak{E}(I)$ for which $\|E\|_{p}<\infty.$ Hewitt hewitt‎, ‎has shown that for $1\leq p\leq\infty$‎, ‎$\frak{E}_p(I)$ is a Banach algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but this would be abstract L^p spaces. I am working on L^p spaces on von Neumann algebras, and as far as I know the info is still spread out in articles, but there is no consolidating book bringing it all together.

Comment: if $d_i=a_i=1$ then $\frak{E}_p(I)=\ell_{p}(I)$

Comment: Of course. I'll have a look when I get back at the office. I am visiting people at the moment. Sorry

Comment: I see what happened there. It's a weighted $\ell^p(I)$ (and if you play around with measures I'm sure you can make it a weighted $L^p(I)$). I'm not sure you need $a_i=1$, but maybe I'm missing something. This may be a long shot, but Fremlin wrote a series of books called Measure Theory that covers a very broad spectrum. It might have something on this topic. Good luck and happy hunting.